# Heroku deploy stuck in build

Tags: heroku, deployment

I want to deploy a MERN stack application to heroku.
Everything is fine when I run `heroku local` but when I want to deploy it loops in build process and keeps running build. no errors in logs.

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "cd server && node server.js",
"client": "cd client && npm start",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
},
```

heroku logs

```
2021-09-22T09:30:16.363135+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user /* my email here */
2021-09-22T09:30:16.363135+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user /* my email here */
2021-09-22T09:30:16.609550+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user /* my email here */
2021-09-22T09:30:16.609550+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user /* my email here */
2021-09-22T09:32:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user /* my email here */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a couple of hours hitting the keyboard with my head I deleted `.git` folder and initialized git again , and deployed, this should work for you if this is the only error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might still get here, there is an option to [clean Heroku build cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache), like so:

Assuming you have the `heroku` CLI installed:

`heroku plugins:install heroku-builds`

Then
`heroku builds:cache:purge -a example-app`

After that, on your next deploy, the build cache will be rebuilt.